# Change window size depending on user control c#

Tags: c#, user-controls, size

So I have a MainForm, in which I got a Panel. 
To this I have created several UserControls that I will put in my Panel on request from different buttons.

My question is: I need to change the windowsize on MainForm depending on which UC I have in the Panel. How do I do this?

I was thinking of creating a public method in MainForm and then call it in the different UC on load, what do you think? Give me your best solutions. Thanks.

Edit: If this is to any help, this is in my MainUC-code to bring in other UC to replace MainUC in panel

```
private void UC1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel MainPanel = MainForm.MainPanel;
        if (!MainPanel.Controls.Contains(UC1.Instance))
        {
            MainPanel.Controls.Add(UC1.Instance);
            UC1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            UC1.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
        else
        {
            UC1.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each `UserControl` you can create an event which is triggered when content should change. For example you can create an event when a button is clicked

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public event OnButtonClicked ButtonClicked;

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ButtonClicked != null)
        {
            ButtonClicked((Button)sender);
        }
    }
}

public delegate void OnButtonClicked(Button button);
```

Then in your `MainForm` you can subscribe to events and change panel content and window size when appropriate.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    MyControl myControl;

    void Subscribe()
    {
        myControl.ButtonClicked += myControl_ButtonClicked;
    }

    void myControl_ButtonClicked(Button button)
    {
        // Change panel content
        // Resize window
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that it does not work? This is only meant to be a guideline code.

Comment: Yes I understand that. I took parts of your code and changed it the way I should. It doesn't work. You want me to post all of my code?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3862d9e7cfc13e2e5738ea54409b6e0e

See if this makes sense. I know it's very messy, It's just raw copy paste. I didn't bother deleting the things you don't need. Sorry for that.

Comment: Please apply the enlisted changes to your code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c31ecd7996b112ee3e2e3d7e97681ef1

Comment: Not a problem. PS. If the answer suits your needs please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: One problem, I want to add more to the subscribe list. How do I do it?
     https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46cd1a42fc06b54b6a8e935bbec0b6e3